# How can I convert a Mat_ to Mat in the following code?

Tags: c++, opencv

below is a snippet from the opencv SVM tutorial at this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html#introductiontosvms).  And in that snippet is this line of code ' Mat sampleMat = (Mat_(1,2) << j,i);'. Instead of using the Mat_ template, I would need to use a regular Mat object.  I was hoping someone can show me how to convert the Mat_ to a Mat in the previous line.

I tried   `Mat sampleMat = (Mat(1,2, CV_32FC1) << j,i);` //but get a long page of errors
I tried  `Mat sampleMat = Mat(1,2, CV_32FC1) << j,i;`  //same,  long page of errors

I just need the code at the link at the top of the page to run without using the Mat_ and only use a Mat in its place...if someone can show me how to write that line I'd appreciate it.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
         for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
         {
             Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
             float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

             if (response == 1)
                 image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = green;
             else if (response == -1)
                  image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = blue;
         }
```

Edit:  Trying to run like below but getting errors

```
 Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {

    Mat sampleMat(1, 2, CV_32F);
    float * const pmat = sampleMat.ptr<float>();
    pmat[0] = i;
    pmat[1] = j;

            float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

            if (response == 1)
         pmat[0]  = green;
        pmat[1] = green;
            else if (response == -1)
          pmat[0]  = blue;
             pmat[1]  = blue;
    }
```

I figured you'd know enough so I didn't need the errors=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the values directly:

```
Mat sampleMat(1, 2, CV_32F);
sampleMat.at<float>(0,1) = j;
sampleMat.at<float>(0,2) = i;
```

or

```
Mat sampleMat(1, 2, CV_32F);
float * const pmat = sampleMat.ptr<float>();
pmat[0] = j;
pmat[1] = i;
```

Addendum:

Seeing your loop, you could make it a bit more efficient in the case that `SVM.predict` doesn't modify `sampleMat`. You can set the image row just once per row, instead of doing it all the time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
{
  Mat sampleMat(1, 2, CV_32F);
  sampleMat.at<float>(0, 2) = i;

  for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
  {
    sampleMat.at<float>(0, 1) = j;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so soon, I was hoping to use the << to assign the data, if that's not possible is there a way you can show me how to assign data with Mat.ptr object in this case...I'm trying to stay  away from Mat.at  because I heard it's slow....

Comment: Mat.at is slow in debug mode, because it does bounds checking there. but blazing fast in release. so have no fear using it !

Comment: I added the version with `ptr`. I usually use `ptr` always, but I thought that the version with `at` is more clear when one starts with OpenCV.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger  Thanks again...you got me past the first part, the matrix, but could use help assigning data to the pmat[0] and pmat[1] seems I have to cast them to Vec3b but couldn't figure it out..getting errors like this on all four assignments

 `cannot convert ‘cv::Vec3b {aka cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>}’ to ‘float’ in assignment
        pmat[0]  = blue;`

Comment: Your first code and the second one is not the same at all. In the first one, you create `sampleMat` with value `[j, i]`, and in the second, with value `[i, j]`. Then, you need braces between your `if` statements. Finally, in your first code you assign `green` to another variable called `image`, but in the second, you try to do it to `sampleMat` via the pointer `pmat`. If `image` is an RGB image (3 channels), you have to access as you did in your first code.